# creating popup window buttons

Tags: javascript

I am creating a site with where the checkout menu has share buttons instead of a check out button. they are giving away free products and are hoping to encourage sharing on social media. I am trying to open a pop up window that will take you to each sites respective share screen. the problem I'm running into is that only one link works, I click the Facebook button and the twitter link pops up.

```js
facebook = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=";
twitter = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=";



function popup() {
  var twit = document.getElementById("twit");
  var face = document.getElementById("face");
  if (twit) {
    var myWindow = window.open(window.location.href = twitter, "", "width=400, height=400");
  }
}
/* else if (face){
window.open(window.location.href = facebook, "", "width=400, height=400");
}
}

 */
function popupFace() {
  var face = document.getElementById("face");
  if (face) {
    var myFbWindow = window.open(window.location.href = facebook, "", "width=400, height=400");
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="twit" onclick="JaveScript:popup()">
  twitter
</button>

<button id="face" onclick="JavaScript:popup()">
  facebook
</button>
```

Comment: both of these button are calling popup() function which goes to twitter. The second one should be calling popupFace()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to sinanspd's comment, which will solve your problem, we can simplify this quite a bit:

```js
const facebook = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=";
const twitter = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=";

function popup(element) {
  if (element.id === 'twit') {
    window.open(window.location.href = twitter, "", "width=400, height=400");
  } else if (element.id === "face") {
    window.open(window.location.href = facebook, "", "width=400, height=400");
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="twit" onclick="popup(this)">
  twitter
</button>

<button id="face" onclick="popup(this)">
  facebook
</button>
```

And if these are the only two buttons that will ever call `popup()` then you can simplify it even more by making the facebook conditional be the else clause; no need for comparison there.

Note that this code snippet works but not within the `"Run code snippet"` window.